# lightdm and gdm broken after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, gdm, lightdm

I upgraded to oneiric. When my machine boots, I get a black console with text messages listing the services that are starting up, and then my machine sits there in that state and lightdm never comes up. I am able to log in by doing control-alt-F1, logging in, and doing a startx by hand.

I tried switching from lightdm to gdm, but that hasn't helped either.

I tried doing `sudo start gdm` but it tells me that gdm is already running.

The file `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` contains `/usr/sbin/gdm`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

My video card is nvidia:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 220] (rev a2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you had proprietary graphics drivers installed.  This would have created an xorg.conf file.  If you rename it, you should be able to boot to a graphical desktop using open-source drivers.  If you have previously blacklisted the open-source drivers, you will need to un-blacklist them.

To rename xorg.conf

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.backup
```

Oneiric is designed around lightdm - therefore reconfigure your display manager

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

`/etc/X11/default-display-manager` should now point to lightdm.

If you are still left with a black-screen, then the opensource nouveau graphics driver is at fault/and or KMS is at fault.

First try booting with `nomodeset` in your GRUB boot options.

You could also try force booting to the low resolution VESA graphics via `xforcevesa` or possibly `xforcevesa nomodeset`.

If you are unsure how to temporily add these GRUB boot options see my linked question.

If these temporary boot options still don't work - you can install the nvidia proprietary graphics driver from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have nvidia video, and I've edited the question to say so. Is lsmod the way to tell what driver I had/have? When the problem first occurred, lsmod said nvidia; I don't know if that's a proprietary driver or an OSS one. There doesn't appear to be anything video-related in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. I renamed xorg.conf, set my display manager to be lightdm, checked that /etc/X11/default-display-manager pointed to lightdm, and rebooted. Lsmod still says nvidia. My system still behaves the same as before.

Comment: ... I've added a few more options to try.  Need to know the exact model of your graphics card - please edit your question and add the output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had binary-blob video drivers installed. Switching to nouveau fixed the lightdm problem, but had the mysterious side-effect of breaking ethernet. Bizarre. I did a fresh install of oneiric, and everything seems to be working fine now. Apparently the problem was something broken about the upgrade path from natty to oneiric.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question after having a similar problem, and solved it a different way after a lot of frustration.
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf was trying to use "unity-greeter" but I changed it to "lightdm-gtk-greeter". This worked for me.  I hope it might help somebody.

Comment: .. in my case it may be relevant that my setup is Mythbuntu and I am running Xfce instead of GNOME or Unity.